# Viewstate and Tab container

Tags: asp.net, tabs, ajaxcontroltoolkit, panel, viewstate

I have the following code for a tab container and i am able to create a tab dynamically but as soon as i try to click to add another tab the previous tab disappears, i can't figure out how to keep viewstate, can someone please help me with this.

## test5.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test5.aspx.cs" Inherits="test5" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<cc1:tabcontainer id="TabContainer1" visible="true" runat="server" Height="150px"> 
    <cc1:TabPanel ID="Tab0" runat="server" HeaderText="Step 1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            Test
            <asp:Button ID="add" Text="Add" OnClick="add_Click" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </cc1:TabPanel> 
</cc1:tabcontainer>  

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## test5.aspx.cs

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test5 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentTab = TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex;
        int nextTab = currentTab + 1;

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "Add" + nextTab.ToString();
        btn.Text = "Add";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(add_Click);


        TabPanel t = new TabPanel();
        t.ID = "Tab" + nextTab;
        t.HeaderText = "Tab:" + nextTab;
        t.Controls.Add(btn);
        TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the controls are dynamically-added, they don't automatically persist through `PostBack` like static controls in the ASPX.  You'll need to store the controls in `ViewState` and re-render them on every `PostBack`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes but i can't figure out how to add everything to viewstate. Do you think you can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

Wrap the following code:

```
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "Add" + nextTab.ToString();
        btn.Text = "Add";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(add_Click);


        TabPanel t = new TabPanel();
        t.ID = "Tab" + nextTab;
        t.HeaderText = "Tab:" + nextTab;
        t.Controls.Add(btn);
        TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(t);
```

Into its own method called `RenderDynamicTabs(int nextTab)`

At the end of `add_Click`, add this code:

```
if(null == ViewState["NumDynamicControls"])
{
    ViewState["NumDynamicControls"] = 0;
}

var dynamicControlCount = int.Parse(ViewState["NumDynamicControls"]);
dynamicControlCount++;
```

In `Page_Load`, add the following:

```
if(null != ViewState["NumDynamicControls"])
{
    // There are controls that need to be re-generated
    var dynamicControlCount = int.Parse(ViewState["NumDynamicControls"]);

    for(int i = 1; i <= dynamicControlCount; i++)
    {
        RenderDynamicTabs(i);
    }
}
```

That should both store and re-render your controls after each `PostBack`.

Finally, to avoid duplication of code, in `add_Click`, replace the code you copy-pasted into `RenderDynamicTabs` with just a call to `RenderDynamicTabs(nextTab);`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, i just tried it but now i am getting this error, not sure why though.      Type 'System.Web.UI.Control' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Aaah, I forgot Controls themselves aren't serializable.  Give me a bit and I'll rework it.

Comment: I just tried that and it gave me an error with the following line
var dynamicControlCount = int.Parse(ViewState["NumDynamicControls"]);

So i added the ToString at the end
var dynamicControlCount = int.Parse(ViewState["NumDynamicControls"].ToString());
and it compiled succesffully but it still doesn't work completely, if i click the first
time it adds one tab, and on the next tab if i click then the new tab disappears and it starts over

Comment: Then it's time to test.  Put some breakpoints in and see if the `ViewState["NumDynamicControls"]` is getting incremented correctly when you click the button to add another.

Comment: Ok will do, and again thanks a lot for your help man, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, I've been breaking my head all weekend with this and can't figure out.

I was able to find that when I add breakpoints the count is always at 0, it seems like the controls are never being saved to viewstate, how can I force the controls to be saved to viewstate? I think that will solve the issue.

Comment: Post your reworked code and I'll try to run it locally and see if I can figure anything out.

Comment: d'oh, I think I figured it out.  We are incrementing the count, but it's not being stored back into ViewState--an oversight on my part.  At the bottom of add_Click, add the following line: `ViewState["NumDynamicControls"] = dynamicControlCount;`

Answer (score 0):

i removed the additions i added before, but here is what i got so far

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test5 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != ViewState["NumDynamicControls"])
        {
            // There are controls that need to be re-generated
            var dynamicControlCount = int.Parse(ViewState["NumDynamicControls"].ToString());

            for (int i = 1; i <= dynamicControlCount; i++)
            {
                RenderDynamicTabs(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RenderDynamicTabs(int nextTab)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = "Add" + nextTab.ToString();
        btn.Text = "Add";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(add_Click);


        TabPanel t = new TabPanel();
        t.ID = "Tab" + nextTab;
        t.HeaderText = "Tab:" + nextTab;
        t.Controls.Add(btn);
        TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(t);

    }

    protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int currentTab = TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex;
        int nextTab = currentTab + 1;

        RenderDynamicTabs(nextTab);


        if (null == ViewState["NumDynamicControls"])
        {
            ViewState["NumDynamicControls"] = 0;
        }

        var dynamicControlCount = int.Parse(ViewState["NumDynamicControls"].ToString());
        dynamicControlCount = dynamicControlCount + 1;
    }
}
```